# Асинхронные вызовы в React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Дан код (https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-lichterman-fkvfn):

```
export default function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = React.useState([]);
  const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);

  const fetchUsers = async () => {
    const resp = await fetch("https://api.github.com/users");
    const data = await resp.json();
    console.log("number", number);
    console.log("data", data);
    setUsers(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            fetchUsers();
          }, 1000);
        }}
      >
        fetch
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setNumber(number + 1)}> click </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Если нажать сначала на кнопку вызова fetchUsers, а после сразу несколько раз на кнопку вызова setNumber, то в методе fetchUsers не будет видно изменения в стейте number. Даже если поставить setTimeout для вызова setNumber. Почему так происходит ?
Изменения в обычной переменной в функции fetchUsers будет видно, но переменная не подходит, если компонент перерендеривается.

Answer (score 0):

При вызове fetchUsers через setTimeout - в fetchUsers будет храниться скоуп на момент вызова setTimeout, возможно стоит написать так:

setTimeout(fetchUsers, 1000);

Очень больная тема с setTimeout в реакте, для того чтобы достать текущее валидное значение есть хак:
setNumber(number => {
// исполняем нужный код с валидным number
return number
})

Comment: > **fetchUsers через setTimeout - в fetchUsers**  -   будет храниться скоуп на момент
Но если создать простую переменную и изменить ее до того, как отработает fetchUsers, то в fetchUsers она будет с актуальным значением. Значит ссылка на актуальный scope

> **чтобы достать текущее валидное значение есть хак**  -  
Смысл тут в том, что во время запроса может произойти различные события и изменения в разных частях интефейса. И в асинхронной функции хотелось бы видеть эти изменения и решать, нужно ли менять стейт или нет.